# Calculate max value of a measure over summary table

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have an Excel table in powerpivot that has a combination of people and the hours they have assigned to each project (`cc_pt2`).  I am trying to calculate for each person, what is the maximum percentage of time they have assigned to a single project. Meaning, if one person has a total of 100 hours and used 20 for one project and 80 for another, the measure should return 80%.

My table is formatted like this:

| month | name | hours | type | cc_pt2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date1 | me | 6,17 | CNA |  |
| date2 | me | 16,5 | PT | 1100 |
| date3 | me | 1,5 | CC | 0300 |

**Source data**

[image: Image of source data]

Not shown here, but this table has a lot more additional columns that are not used for this particular report. It is important, however, that as a result of this there will be multiple rows for each combination of `month` & `name` & `type` & `cc_pt2`. That is why I (think) need to summarize the table to just `name` and `cc_pt2` before calculating the maximum.

Because rows identified with `type="CNA"` shouldn't count towards the total of hours assigned to a project, the resulting measure for this particular person should return 92%, since 16.5 hours where assigned to project 1100 over a total of 18 hours.

I have tried creating a measure (`tmp_prc`) like this:

```
=CALCULATE(
MAXX(
    SUMMARIZE(tb_historico; [name]; [cc_pt2]; "PRCHH"; SUM([hours])/CALCULATE(SUM([hours]);ALL(tb_historico[cc_pt2]))
    )
; [PRCHH]
); tb_historico[type]<>"CNA")
```

This however returns 100% when placed in a pivot table with name as row header.

If I remove the need to filter out `type="CNA"` I can sort of make it work with the following measure (`tmp_prc2`):

```
=MAXX(
    SUMMARIZE(tb_historico; [name]; [cc_pt2]; "PRCHH"; SUM([hours])/CALCULATE(SUM([hours]);ALL(tb_historico[cc_pt2]))
    )
; [PRCHH]
)
```

This works as long as I don't place `type` in the filter of the pivot table and try to filter by it.

I have also tried different combinations of where to place the filter for `type`, like inside the expresion for the SUMMARIZE function instead, but with the same results.

**Pivot Table**

[image: Results in pivot table]

The end result I would like is to have a pivot table that for each person calculates the maximum percent assigned to a project. A format like this, but with correct value shown instead of 68%:

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Because rows identified with [type]="CNA" souldn't count towards the total of hours assigned to a project

If that's the case, I would remove that first.

```
=MAXX(
    SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER('tb_historico',[type]<>"CNA"); 
    [name]; [cc_pt2]; "PRCHH"; SUM([hours])/CALCULATE(SUM([hours]);ALL(tb_historico[cc_pt2]))
    )
; [PRCHH]
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the same result as in the measure "tmp_prc" shown in the pivot table image of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language settings of your Excel version, please decide whether to use a semicolon or a comma.

```
=CALCULATE(
    IF(
        ISBLANK(MIN(tb_historico[cc_pt2])),
        BLANK(),
        DIVIDE(
            SUMX(
                FILTER(
                    tb_historico,
                    tb_historico[type] <> "CNA"
                ),
                [hours]
            ),
            SUMX(
                FILTER(
                    ALL(tb_historico),
                    tb_historico[type] <> "CNA"
                ),
                [hours]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

---

**Update**

Question: show me the maximum percent that person has assigned

```
=MAXX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        tb_historico,
        tb_historico[cc_pt2],
        "MaxValue",
        CALCULATE(
            IF(
                ISBLANK(MIN(tb_historico[cc_pt2])),
                BLANK(),
                DIVIDE(
                    SUMX(
                        FILTER(
                            tb_historico,
                            tb_historico[type] <> "CNA"
                        ),
                        [hours]
                    ),
                    SUMX(
                        FILTER(
                            ALL(tb_historico),
                            tb_historico[type] <> "CNA"
                        ),
                        [hours]
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    [MaxValue]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I should have been more specific in a couple of things (I will edit the original question): I don't want the pivot table to show me the percent assigned to each project, I would like it to show me the maximum percent that person has assigned. I will be using the pivot table with just the person's names in the row header.

Comment: I have updated the DAX.